# How to set master page on page preinit based on custom user control method result

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, preinit

I have a user control that checks if a certain query string and session value are present then returns a boolean based on that, if it's true I want to set the master page.

The page is throwing an Object reference exception when it tries to call the method `EditUser1.UserAuthorization()`. Why is this happening? I imagine that the method doesn't exist at that point in the stack.

```
Protected Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    If EditUser1.UserAuthorization(True) Then
        Page.MasterPageFile = "APERSEmpCont.master"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what EditUser1 is, is that your custom control?  And UserAuthorization is a method of it?  If so you need to include that source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events), that the page controls haven't been initialized at the point of the preinit, so that method doesn't exist at that moment. I'll have to move the method to the page level to make it work.